# How to change color for columns which categorised to single model property? Kendo Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My datas are like that:

- 4, FirstCategory
- 2, SecondCategory
- 5, ThirdCategory
- 7, FourthCategory
- 4,2,5,7  --> model.Value comes like that
- FirstCategory,..., FourthCategory --> model.Range comes like that.

But all colums have same color. Is there a solution to give different colors to different columns?

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model) .Name("chart")
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series
                   .Column(model => model.Value, categoryExpression: model => model.Range)
                   .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Count)
                 .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Position(ChartBarLabelsPosition.Center));

        })
```